# Keeping track of data not in a table view?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

In every  tutorial I've seen dealing with keeping track of submitted user data, table views / collection views are used in conjunction with arrays + indexPath.row to keep track of which post is which.

I'm working on an app where multiple users are able to make posts, but instead of a tableview, I'm wanting the posts to be contained in buttons that can be moved around on the screen freely.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to keep track of which post is which when it's outside of a structured tableview where the indexes match up.

I'm using firebase as a backend, and so ideally when a user clicks on a post button it'd load up the corresponding post..which would normally be done by grabbing the indexpath.row out of a saved array from firebase. I've got a working app using tableviews so I'm definitely not asking on how to retrieve data from firebase or anything, but moreso how to transition to the button concept.

So basically, how do you keep track of posts or "things" on a screen when they're not in a list-format? This sort of thing is done all of the time in games seemingly?.. but I'm not sure how to apply that same kind of logic into a non-game app.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, table views provide a framework where each cell as an "address" (the indexPath) and it's straightforward to look up the data for a cell.

If you're going to have a free-floating bunch of buttons then the burden is on you to come up with a scheme for keeping track of which one is which.

One simple way to do this would be to set the tag property on the buttons, and then in the IBAction for the buttons interrogate the tag value and use it as an index into your data. (Note that you should not use tag 0 as a tag that serves as an index since 0 is the "this field does not have a tag" value. In situations like this I usually add some fixed value like 100 to my tag values, and then subtract that from the tag before using it as an array index.

Answer (score 0):

UI elements have a `.tag` property that you could use to keep track of them. Whatever system you end up going with should have key-value pairings, with some part of the button (whether that's its tag or the actual object or a hash of the object) to be able to reference them. Like how TableView key values are key: IndexPath, value: UITableViewCell.

Since your items are in an array, you could have the index within the array correspond to a button.

So create an NSArray of buttons of the same size as your data array. Instantiate the buttons so that they appear on the screen and have visual properties as you would like. When the user selects a button, check the tag of the button, which corresponds to the index of the data array that you would read out of.

Answer (score 0):

I'd store all the buttons in some collection, but it wouldn't use the collection index.

I'd create a new class which has a reference to a model object and some function to provide display details to the view and handlers for interaction (a view model) and give one of those to each button. Then you don't need to worry about indexes because you already have references to the appropriate information.